# integer positive or negative check

Tags: c++, integer

A little question that I was interested in knowing the answer of.
If I have an integer and I wish to know if it's negative or positive, I would do :

```
if (n > 0)
else
```

but I could also use bit-wise operators like so :

```
if (n >> (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1) == 0)
else
```

is there performance difference ?
Note that I don't know ASM so viewing the disassembly won't really help ME, so I'm only looking for a yes / no answer really.

Comment: Have you looked at the disassembly? If you could paste that here, that would be helpful to analyze the difference.

Comment: `n >> 7 == 0` would only work if the integer is 8-bit, which is generally not true in most cases.  These are the sort of optimizations that you don't need to worry about at all as a compiler would normally take care of it, but since we have no idea what language you're using...

Comment: Any reasonable compiler is going to compile `if (n > 0)` to something that you can't beat (at least not with some other conditional). This isn't on the list of "things that compilers are not smart enough yet to do", this is on the "even the compiler you make in university can do it properly"-list.

Comment: @Coda17 my bad fixed to >> 31, and I've added a language tag

Comment: The first case has one compare, the second has a shift and a compare - what do you expect to gain ?

Comment: @PaulR I don't really know the cost of basic operators in a language but is comparison is equal to checking if is greater or lesser than operator ?

Comment: Others have already mentioned this, but you do NOT need to care about this level of detail until you start analyzing a program and determine a certain part is taking too long.  It's very likely the compiler will optimize `n > 0` to something faster than you can do in code.  As a programmer, you should care more about legibility when you read the code later.  What's easier to read? `if (n > 0)` or `if (n >> (sizeof(int) * 8 -1) == 0)`?

Comment: @Coda17 I doubt I will ever check for positive/negative number like that, I'm just asking out of curiosity. But let's assume it won't optimize the number, let's assume the variable is a volatile variable, what would actually be faster

Comment: @dikson231: it's not so much the language, as the code that the compiler generates and how this is then executed on the target CPU. But unless you reduce the number of *operations* somehow then you are unlikely to see any gains - your "optimisation" is more likely to be a "de-optimisation".

Answer (score 3):

> is there performance difference ? ... so I'm only looking for a yes / no answer

A simple yes/no answer is: "**no**, just don't do it." Your compiler will take care of such micro-optimisations for you. It will *most definitely* be programmed to implement `n > 0` as efficiently as possible.

If anything, yould succeed in confusing it by the bit-shift hack and make it produce something suboptimal, but I sincerely doubt that. Write what you mean, and leave the micro-optimisation bits to the professionals who wrote the optimiser.

Comment: I think the NO really means "don't do silly things" than there is no difference.

Comment: Just to make it more interesting let's assume the compiler won't optimize this and n is volatile

Comment: @dikson231 Debating performance of non-optimised code is pointless. That's like determining the fastest runner by having the contestants compute long division.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it is entirely compiler dependent.

Generally speaking, you need to accept that intuiting about the performance of C code is highly error prone, because compilers are smart and do surprising things.

If you care about the performance of something in a given environment, you need to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

ARM's CPSR register allows one the check comparisons of greater than and less than for both signed and unsigned operations. This means that your second version will probably be slower (and less reliable when word sizes change) than the first. (see [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHCJFJG.html)). I cannot imagine Intel will be any different.

Comment: IE the answer to his question is "Yes, there can be a difference, though it depends on circumstances.